# How to add Node data and Link data dynamically in GoJS?

Tags: javascript, addition, gojs

```
 myDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(
[

  { key: "Alpha", color: "lightblue" },
  { key: "Delta", color: "pink" }

],
[
  { from: "Alpha", to: "Alpha" },
  { from: "Delta", to: "Alpha" }
]);
```

I need to add more values dynamically, how should I do this?

Comment: You need to check the API for `GraphLinksModel` to see how you add to it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Node data** (source: [GoJS docs, class Model](http://www.gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Model.html)):

> If you want to add or remove node data from the nodeDataArray, call the [addNodeData](http://www.gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Model.html#addNodeData) or [removeNodeData](http://www.gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Model.html#removeNodeData) methods.

**Link data** (source: [GoJS docs, class GraphLinksModel](http://www.gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/GraphLinksModel.html)):

> If you want to add or remove link data from the linkDataArray, call the [addLinkData](http://www.gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/GraphLinksModel.html#addLinkData) or [removeLinkData](http://www.gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/GraphLinksModel.html#removeLinkData) methods. If you want to modify the node a link connects to, call the [setFromKeyForLinkData](http://www.gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/GraphLinksModel.html#setFromKeyForLinkData) and/or [setToKeyForLinkData](http://www.gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/GraphLinksModel.html#setToKeyForLinkData) methods.

Answer (score 0):

An example of dynamically adding from an object list to a [GraphLinksModel](https://gojs.net/latest/samples/minimal.html):

```
       var model = new go.GraphLinksModel();
        for(let id = 1; id < node_list.length; id++){
       model.addNodeData( { key: node_list[id].getNodeID(), color: "lightblue" } );
       model.addLinkData( { from: node_list[id].getPreviousNode(), to: node_list[id].getNodeID() } );
         }
       myDiagram.model = model;  
       console.log(model.nodeDataArray); //to see data
```