# Use custom object for linkData in in gojs when user adds a link

Tags: angular, gojs

Similar to [How to add Node data and Link data dynamically in GoJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28525407/how-to-add-node-data-and-link-data-dynamically-in-gojs), but I want to handle the user adding a link by adding one of my custom objects. In other words, at setup time, I have the following:

```
   customArray: MyModel[] = getMyLinkArray();
   this.diagram.model.addLinkDataCollection(customArray)
```

Now when the user goes to add a link, I want to add a link that is derived from a MyModel object I will supply. It should get the gojs properties added in the same way as is done in addLinkDataCollection.

Presumably this means I should intercept a call somewhere, supply my model object, and tell gojs to use that. But I'm not sure what to intercept, how, or even if it is possible.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Set https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/LinkingTool.html#archetypeLinkData to an instance of `MyModel` with the property values that you want all new link data to have. You can set this when you initialize the Diagram.

```
  $(go.Diagram, . . .,
    { . . .,
      "linkingTool.archetypeLinkData": new MyModel()
    })
```

Set https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/GraphLinksModel.html#copyLinkDataFunction to a function that takes and returns a copy of `MyModel`. You will need to set this on each new model that you load.

```
  var m = go.Model.fromJson(...);
  m.copyLinkDataFunction = function(d) { return ...; };
  myDiagram.model = m;
```

I do suggest renaming the class to be something like `MyLinkModel`.